# How to update status of current fiscal year and add new fiscal year using MySQL event scheduler?

Tags: mysql

I have a table name tbl_fy, I want that status should change automatically from Y to N by the given fy_end_date: 6/30/2021 and meanwhile it also add new fiscal year record in new rows from 7/1/2021 to 6/30/2022.Please help me senior developer in this regard and provide me MySQL event scheduler code in MySQL I will be grateful to you.

```
+===========+===============+=============+=========+===============+=================+=================+
| fy_doc_id | fy_start_date | fy_end_date | fy_year | fy_active_sts | maker_datetime  | update_datetime |
+===========+===============+=============+=========+===============+=================+=================+
|         1 | 7/1/2018      | 6/30/2019   | 2018-19 | N             | 2/22/2021 11:07 | 6/2/2021 12:02  |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|         2 | 7/1/2019      | 6/30/2020   | 2019-20 | N             | 8/19/2020 4:10  | 6/2/2021 12:02  |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|         3 | 7/1/2020      | 6/30/2021   | 2020-21 | Y             | 8/19/2020 4:10  |                 |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Can you share what you already tried?

Comment: @Rui Costa i tried but my code make no sense CREATE EVENT fy_close
ON SCHEDULE  AT fy_end_date
DO
  update messages
    SET fy_active_sts = 'N' WHERE fy_active_sts='Y';